# PayPal with Braintree Drop-In

Tags: javascript, paypal, braintree

I'm trying to get PayPal payments to work with my Braintree dropin integration on my website.

I am 100% sure that I'm doing it completely wrong.

The Braintree docs can get a little bit confusing at times.

What happens is that nothing shows up in my Braintree vault when completing the PayPal payment.

```
braintree.dropin.create({
        authorization: 'TOKEN_GOES_HERE',
        container: '#dropin-container',
        paypal: {
                    flow: 'vault',
                    amount: '1.00',
                    currency: 'EUR'
                }
    },

    function (createErr, instance) {
        doPay.on('click', function () {
            requestPayment(instance);
        });
});

function requestPayment(instance){
    instance.requestPaymentMethod(function (err, payload) {
       var data = { reqPay: payload.nonce
                  }
       $.ajax({ type: 'POST', url: 'buyThing.php', data: data, success:
           function (response) {
               console.log("DONE!");
           }
       });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Braintree drop-in doesn't create customer in the vault, all it does is create a payment nonce. You need to send the nonce generated by the drop-in along with customer info to the backend and do [Braintree_Customer::find()](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/customer/find/php), if customer doesn't exist in vault then do [Braintree_Customer::create()](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/customer/create/php) to create.  After that it's to use the customer paymentMethods from the customer create call to create transaction.

Comment: I am doing all of those things already before adding the PayPal option.

Comment: @KarlAnthonyBaluyot yes. It was a long time though.